# WordPress: Why Can't get_terms() See Custom Taxonomy Registered inside Class?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, custom-taxonomy

## Background

I register a custom post type and custom taxonomy inside a class. Inside the WP admin, I see both the post type, and I see the taxonomy.

#### Simplified Code:

```
class Custom_Post_Type {

    function __construct($init_data) {

        if ( is_admin() ) {

            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_ctp' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'create_ctp_icons' ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_ctp_custom_metadata' ), 1, 2 );

        }

    }

    function create_ctp_taxonomy() {
            register_taxonomy(
                $post_type.'_type',
                $post_type,
                array(
                    'labels' => array(
                        'name' => $taxonomy_label,
                        'add_new_item' => 'Add New '.$taxonomy_label
                    ),
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_tagcloud' => true,
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'show_admin_column' => true
                )
            );

            register_post_type($post_type_slug,
                array(
                    'labels' => array(),
                    'public' => true,
                    'has_archive' => false,
                    'supports' => $this->supports,
                    'register_meta_box_cb' => array( $this, 'create_ctp_custom_metaboxes' ),
                    'taxonomies' => array( $taxonomy_slug ),
                )
            );
    }

}
```

Again, this works inside the admin area. I can add posts, and I can see the taxonomy and add terms.

---

## Problem

On the front end, `get_taxonomies()` doesn't see the new custom taxonomy, and `get_terms()` doesn't see the terms inside it.

I tried several examples of of `register_taxonomy`, and when I used it outside of the class, it appears on the front end. However, when I moved the examples into my internal create_ctp_taxonomy function, they are suddenly invisible to `get_taxonomies`.

Any ideas why this would be occurring?

---

### Edit

I've been playing around with different things and I think the issue here is the timing of the `init` action. When I call the setup function direction from the `__construct` function, rather than adding an action, then things start working. Example:

```
class Custom_Post_Type {

    function __construct($init_data) {

        if ( is_admin() ) {

            //add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'create_ctp' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'create_ctp_icons' ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_ctp_custom_metadata' ), 1, 2 );
        }

        $this->create_cpt();

    }

}
```

By doing this, I skip using `init` at all. However, this seems to violate standard practice. Is there a downside that anyone knows of for doing it this way?

Comment: not sure if there is code missing above, but $post_type is not defined in your function prob meant to be $this->post_type ?

Comment: It is simplified code for an example. In the real code is is as you said, `$this->slug.`

Comment: ok not that so, where do you create your class object ?

Comment: I create it in the functions.php file. (Technically in an included file in the functions file, but I've tested directly in functions.php, and there is no difference.)

Comment: it should add the hook correctly then, your code looks fine, just I meant were you creating the object on init or something...that might lead to timing differences. If i were you i would var_dump some variables and exit within the function to make sure everything is ok, I use classes to register posts/ taxs with no problem in the same way. you can also check global $wp_filter to see if you actions are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not Problems

**1.) The problem isn't a race condition.**

Conditionals like `is_admin()` still work when run from `functions.php` directly. This contradicts some information on the web, but as of WordPress 4.4, these do work.

**2.) Calling the registration from `add_action()` rather than directly from `__construct()`**

Switching to calling the registration directly had zero change. To be clear, there is no difference between:

- `$this->create_ctp()`
- `add_action('init', array( $this, 'create_ctp' ) );`

**3.) Order of registering taxonomy vs CTP**

When I moved my registration of the taxonomy in front of the CTP, it had zero change in behavior.

---

## The Problem

I was using a conditional check of `is_admin()`, which I'd added previous to wrap when I added the admin dashicon. This is why my CTP was appearing on the backend, but not on the front.

I had removed it from my simplified example, so there was no way to tell from looking at the code that I'd posted.

So all I needed to do was remove the `is_admin()` check. A silly mistake it turns out, but useful to find the information about what things aren't actually problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to be aware of when registering taxonomies to custom post types.

1. Register the taxonomies first. This seems a bit counter intuitive but taxonomies are registered to post types, so they need to exist before the post type is created.
2. You also need to register the taxonomy to the post type using the taxonomies argument of the `register_post_type` function.

Eg.

```
 register_post_type('cpt_name',array(
        'taxonomies'=>array(
              'taxomony_name1',
              'taxomony_name2')
         ,other_arguments...)
 );
```

From the **[docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)**

> When registering a post type, always register your taxonomies using
>   the taxonomies argument. If you do not, the taxonomies and post type
>   will not be recognized as connected when using filters such as
>   parse_query or pre_get_posts. This can lead to unexpected results and
>   failures

Comment: After investigating, neither of these changes have any effect. The docs do suggest both, but when I made the changes, they didn't do anything at all. I did update the code in my question to reflect the corrected way though, because there isn't a downside to ordering them correctly.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted :)